$M^k$ x for a general $M$.
Suppose I have a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$. Let $x$ be some random vector. For convenience, let $x_i$ ~ $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Again, I will be interested in more general constraints on $x$, but let's start there. I'm interested, in general, in the behaviour of $M^k x$ as k $\rightarrow \infty$.
Now, if $M$ is symmetric positive definite I wanted to start by showing show that $M^k x$ will be aligned, with the first eigenvector $v_1$ of $M$. We can show that the vectors become aligned by showing that the quantity $$Q(k) = \frac{\lVert(M^k x)_{\Vert} \Vert^2_2}{\lVert M^k x \rVert_2} = \frac{\langle M^kx, v_1\rangle}{\lVert M^k x \rVert_2 \lVert v_1 \rVert_2} = \cos_{\angle(M^k x,  v_1)}$$.
converges to 1 in probability as $k \rightarrow \infty$. We can use the fact that $M^k=S\Lambda S^T$ using the diagonalisation of $M$ into an orthonormal $S$ and $\Lambda^k = diag\left\{\lambda_1^k, \lambda_2^k, \ldots \right\}$. We obtain
$$\begin{align}
p(k) &= \mathbb{P} \large\{ 1 - Q(k) > \epsilon \large\} \\
&= \mathbb{P} \left\{ 1 -\frac{\lVert (M^k x)_{\Vert} \rVert^2_2}{\lVert M^k x \rVert_2} > \epsilon \right\} \\
&= \mathbb{P} \left\{1 - \frac{\lVert (S \Lambda^k S^T x)_{\Vert} \rVert^2_2}{\sqrt{\langle S \Lambda^k S^T x, S \Lambda^k S^T x \rangle}} > \epsilon \right\} \\
\end{align}$$
where the $s_i$ are the coordinates of $x$ in the basis $S$. Briefly, you get:
\begin{align}
&= \mathbb{P} \left\{ 1 - \frac{\lambda_1^{k} s_1}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^{2k} s_i^2}} > \epsilon \right\} \\
&= \mathbb{P} \left\{1 - \frac{\lambda_1^{k}}{\sqrt{\lambda_1^{2k}}}\frac{s_1}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\lambda_i^{2k}}{\lambda_1^{2k}} s_i^2}} > \epsilon \right\} \\
\end{align}
$$
then
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} \left\{1 - Q(k) > \epsilon \right\} = \mathbb{P} \left\{ 1 - \frac{s_1}{s_1 \sqrt{ 0 + \ldots + 0}} > \epsilon \right\} = 0\\
$$
This last bit is admittedly a bit handwavy. But you get the idea. Now, first question: I'm a bit surprised. I would have expected a square to show up in the $s_i$. Because $S$ is orthonormal the $s_i$ and because the Gaussian is rotation invariant, we have $s_i$ ~ $x_i$. But this means if we take the expectation now for any finite $k$, that's just gonna be 0.
Second question: how would I do this for a more general matrix (keeping $x$ fixed for now)? SVD comes to mind, but it doesn't work because $U$, and $V^T$ don't square off as nicely? Is there a quick way to do it, or is the most general way the Jordan-route?

Sorry, I'm only interested in square matrices for now. Will correct that now. This was originally going to be a completely different question.
